# Prevent powershell script arguments with asterisk from expanding into separate file names when passed to Java program

Tags: powershell

I have written a basic powershell script like this:

```
$ "java.exe" "-cp" "." $args
```

My test Java program:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(String arg : args) System.out.println(arg);
}
```

I use this script to run a Java program like this:

```
.\test.ps1 com.test.Test *.txt
```

I expect/want for this program to print this:

```
*.txt
```

Instead it prints out every file name that matches the file card in that directory like this:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can prevent the wildcard expansion in the powershell script?  I have tried putting double and single quotes around the &args and that doesn't work.  I tried splitting all the arguments into another array and that didn't work.

Update 1:

```
.\test.ps1 "*.txt"
```

Results in the same results:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

Update 2:

```
.\test.ps1 \*.txt
```

Results in an incorrect argument printed:

```
\*.txt
```

## Solution

I *finally* figured this out.  You need to re-populate and quote the arguments in the powershell script like this:

```
$QuotedArguments = @() #Creating an array of arguments
foreach($arg in $args)
{
    #This is done because arguments with * may be expanded
    #into matching file names instead of left alone
    $QuotedArguments += """$arg"""
}
$ "java.exe" "-cp" "." $QuotedArguments
```

Comment: A `test.ps1` file just contaiing `$args` outputs the arguments as is without expanding, so I'm not that shure at which the expand takes place.

Comment: Accoreding to answers in the linked Question it might be the java runtime library which does the expanding.

Comment: I looked at the "duplicate" question but it doesn't solve this problem so I don't think it is the same.  E.g. test.ps1 "*.txt" results in the same behavior and test.ps1 \\*.txt results in the argument printed being: "\\*.txt". '*.txt' also results in all the txt files being printed.

Comment: Also, it looks like the duplicate is asking about *nix shells, not powershell.

Comment: The common point is java and the assumption that it's the rtl.